# display Kb loaded by browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, load, loader, user-experience

I have to load an Animate Canvas file with some heavy images, also a few JS files as  in the html file. I would like to display a loader with the KB/MB that are loaded while the user waits before the app starts.

Is there any way to know how much KB are loaded from the browser in JS?

Comment: `performance.getEntries().map(x=>x.encodedBodySize).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)` works for texty resources, but afaik, there's no image equivalent; you need to build and ship a map/dictionary of url+sizes your script can use to make such calculations (you can tell if an image is arrived via `performance.getEntries()`, but not it's size)

Comment: Thank you this is useful, and I see that the encodedBodySize property appears as well for images than for all other type of resource. So I imagine working with a timer that checks every second the sum of all encodedBodySize Vs the sum of all decodedBodySize? (to display a % loaded indicator)